# CSS fixed background image

Tags: css

I am trying to add a background image to my website which is fixed, I have done this before and had no problems, but now I just can not seem to get it to work, below is my code.  At the moment as I scroll up and down on the website the background moves up and down as well.

```
 body{
background-image: url('../img/christmas.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please put your codes in JSFiddle.

Comment: remove  jquery.stellar.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(After seeing your page-link in Chrome (Happens in Chrome only))...
Start by removing your script that creates a **parallax effect** in chrome. **jquery.stellar.js**

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/uqsftdgc/)***

```
html, body{height:100%;}
body{
    background: url('../img/christmas.jpg') fixed 50% / cover;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Comment: Also I think that some older mobile devices will not load properly the Google's Open sans so go always with a fallback: `'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: @sam003 as you can clearly see from the demo, it works. The website content scrolls but the body's bg is in-place. It's fixed. No scrolling background.

Comment: @sam003 probably... You're not copy-pasteing my code correctly - or you're doing something terribly wrong :) any link to share? I might inspect the elements and see what's going on *in-situ*.

Comment: thanks, I saw the demo, and i added your code to my style sheet, but its not working here is a short url to my page.    goo.gl/YZ3fj0

Comment: @sam003 I opened the website and the bg is fixed exactly like it should be. Have you cleared your cache? (ctrl+F5)

Comment: @Sam003 I've seen the issue on your link **in Chrome only**, you're using a script that creates a parallax effect on the background. Remove that script. (*Stellar* or something...)

Comment: OK so it seems like it doesn't fix in chrome firefox is perfect but chrome isn't